# PHP api on linux machine throwing Connection Refused error on accessing

Tags: php, node.js, linux, apache

I have hosted website and api on apache server on `linux` machine. I am trying to access the `api` through node js (using request module)which is on the same network. From outside that network, the api is accessible and working fine. I have many apis on the machine and only few are throwing this error. Recent change which was made to server is changing the cookie domain from `foo.bar.com to *.bar.com` in php.ini file. The website is working good. There is not much load on the server too. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A "connection refused" error means a TCP connection can't be established, so the cookie domain change should not have an effect here.

- Are you sure it's a Node.js "connection refused" error, and not, say, the API itself being able to connect somewhere else? Can you give us the exact error message, with any traceback, etc., context?

You say there are many APIs (assuming API servers) on the machine and only some fail (assuming you tested this from the machine that is having problems connecting to the API server machine).

- Are the working servers on different ports compared to the non-working ones?
- Do those servers work from within the network? You say they're working fine outside of it. (It's possible that your local network has a firewall policy that prohibits this local connection.)
- Can you double-check that the non-working servers are actually running? (An easy way to establish this would be running `ss -ltpn`; it should give you a list of listening TCP ports and their associated processes.)

Comment: Looks like node js has to be updated. Currently the machine is running v0.12.7 node. Will try and get back with results.